# Facebook 6th June 2012 Changes

Tags: api, fbml

Facebook developer roadmap is available at : http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/
This says - 
 **June 6th 2012**
*"Removal of FBML - FBML apps will no longer work on Platform. All FBML endpoints will be removed."*

We have one application, which is of canvas type "IFrame". In this app, we are using Ajax.FBML and setInnerFBML methods.So, will these be affected because of 6th June 2012 change?

Also, our app uses "fb:profile-pic" tag at many places to show the user photos from Facebook.Will that get affected because of the FBML changes?

Regards,
KK

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're using FBML therefore you'll be affected when FBML is removed - you should change your app ASAP to use iframes, and use the API to retrieve any user data you need instead of having Facebook render it for you